# Moving jdbc connection to property files in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am bit new to JSP and JDBC, I want to know how to move a JDBC connection like below to a property file for example to test.properties

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
//Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@nyvm0467.ptc.un.org:1521:EIDMSUAT", "DBO_EIDMSUAT", "NewPassDBO_EIDMSUAT");
Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:", "ROD", "DMSP");                     
Statement statement = conn.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );  
String queryString = "select area from helparea order by area";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
```

Comment: What is the context here? If you're already using JSPs, you must be using a servlet container or application server, which gives you the ability to define a data source in a property/XML file out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is as follows. correct me if I am wrong

```
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("C:\\Users\\S.Mandava\\workspace2\\Contactus\\src\\OIMConnection");
String name=resource.getString("dbname");
String surname=resource.getString("dbpassword"); 

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 

Connection  conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@eidms-db-003.un.org:1521:EIDPMDM", resource.getString("dbname"), resource.getString("dbpassword"));
Statement statement2 = conn2.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );  
String queryString2 = "select area from helparea order by area";
ResultSet rs2 = statement2.executeQuery(queryString2);
```